# Searching in Lucene provides 0 results

Tags: java, lucene

I am using *Lucene 6.4.0* and use the following code.

But for each query it returns **0** results. Code seems to be correct and index is also being built but I am not able to know where I am going wrong.

```
public void buildIndex(){

        Connection con = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        IndexWriter writer=null;
        StandardAnalyzer analyzer = null;       


        analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();




        IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);

        try{
            System.out.println("Start indexing");
            //get a reference to index directory filejdbc:mysql://localhost/MTDATABASE


            writer =  new IndexWriter(FSDirectory.open(file.toPath()), config);

            //initialize the driver class
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            //get connection object
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://"+DB_HOST_NAME+"/MTDATABASE",
                    DB_USER_NAME, DB_PASSWORD);
            //create statement object
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            //execute query
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM products");
            //iterate through result set
            while(rs.next()){
                productId = rs.getInt("productId");
                productImageName = rs.getString("productImageName");
                productCategory = rs.getString("productCategory");
                productBrandName = rs.getString("productBrandName");
                productType = rs.getString("productType");
                productName = rs.getString("productName");
                prop1 = rs.getString("prop1");
                prop2 = rs.getString("prop2");
                prop3 = rs.getString("prop3");
                prop4 = rs.getString("prop4");
                prop5 = rs.getString("prop5");
                description = rs.getString("description");
                price = rs.getInt("price");
                discount = rs.getFloat("discount");
                cashback = rs.getFloat("cashback");
                availability = rs.getString("availability");

                //create a full text field which contains name,
                //age and designation
                String fulltext = productId + " " + productImageName +
                " " + productCategory+" "+productBrandName+" "+productType+
                " " + productName + " "+prop1+" "+prop2+" "+prop3+" "+prop4+" "+prop5+
                " "+description+" "+price+" "+discount+" "+cashback+" "+availability;


                /*doc.add(new StringField("id",
                        Integer.toString(id), StringField.Store.YES));
                        doc.add(new TextField("title", title,
                        TextField.Store.YES));
                        w.addDocument(doc);*/

                //create document object


                addDoc(writer,productId,productImageName,productCategory,productBrandName,productType,
                        productName,prop1,prop2,prop3,prop4,prop5,description,price,discount,cashback,availability);
                writer.close();



            }




        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try{
                if(writer!=null)
                    writer.close();
                if(rs!=null)
                    rs.close();
                if(stmt!=null)
                    stmt.close();
                if(con!=null)
                    con.close();
                System.out.println("Finished indexing");

            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        IndexBuilder builder = new IndexBuilder();
        builder.buildIndex();
    }






private  void addDoc(IndexWriter w, int productId, String      productImageName,String productCategory,String productBrandName,String    productType,
                String productName,String prop1,String prop2,String    prop3,String prop4,String prop5,
                String description,int price,float discount,float   cashback,String availability) throws IOException {
   Document doc = new Document();
   doc.add(new StringField("produciId",Integer.toString(productId),   StringField.Store.YES));

   doc.add(new StringField("productImageName",productImageName,StringField.Store.YES));

   doc.add(new TextField("productCategory",productCategory,TextField.Store.YES));

   doc.add(new TextField("productBrandName",productBrandName,TextField.Store.YES));

   doc.add(new TextField("productType",productType,TextField.Store.YES));

   doc.add(new TextField("productName",productName,TextField.Store.YES));

   doc.add(new TextField("prop1",prop1,TextField.Store.YES));

   doc.add(new TextField("prop2",prop2,TextField.Store.YES));

   doc.add(new TextField("prop3",prop3,TextField.Store.YES));

   doc.add(new TextField("prop4",prop4,TextField.Store.YES));

   doc.add(new TextField("prop5",prop5,TextField.Store.YES));

   doc.add(new StringField("description",description,StringField.Store.YES));

   doc.add(new StringField("price",Integer.toString(price),StringField.Store.YES));

   doc.add(new StringField("discount",Float.toString(discount),StringField.Store.YES));

   doc.add(new StringField("cashback",Float.toString(cashback),StringField.Store.YES));

   doc.add(new StringField("availability",availability,StringField.Store.YES));

   w.addDocument(doc);
}
```

And for search I'am using:

```
public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{

            String LUCENE_INDEX_DIRECTORY = "C:\\lucene";

            File file = new File(LUCENE_INDEX_DIRECTORY);

            Directory index = FSDirectory.open(file.toPath());

            StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();

            String query = "mountain";
            QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("productName",analyzer);
            Query q = null;
            q=parser.parse(query);

            int hitsPerPage = 10;
            IndexReader reader=null;
            TopScoreDocCollector collector = null;
            IndexSearcher searcher = null;

            reader=DirectoryReader.open(index);
            searcher=new IndexSearcher(reader);

            collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(10);
            searcher.search(q,collector);
            ScoreDoc[] hits=collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;
            System.out.println(hits.length);
            if(hits.length>0){
                for(int i=0; i<hits.length; i++){
                int docId = hits[i].doc;

                Document document = searcher.doc(docId);

                System.out.println("BrandName is: "+document.get("productBrandName")+"and ProductName is: "+document.get("productName")+
                                   "productCategory is: "+document.get("productCategory")+"and prop is:"+document.get("prop1"));

            }


        }else{
            System.out.println("Not Done");

        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Not done ... ");
    }




}
```

}

Comment: Everything looks ok. Only thing I have noticed is that your example doesnt define `file` for the index building. Stupid question, are you definitely writing your index to `c:\\lucene`? Have you checked to see if the index files exist?

Comment: Not a stupid question.Index file was created at that location @TedTrippin

Comment: I adapted the lucene code and it worked fine (manually added a productName=mountain. Only thing I can suggest is follow Zheng's suggestion of using Luke or add lots of logging to check that everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, the first thing might be use the Luke to open the search database to see if your content were really wrote into the search index.

https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke

And also double check if there were any value in the "productName" being populated.

Once you can certain the integrity of your index is good, then you can check does the search word "mountain" are really being a valid search term.